# What is the optimal snooze time for a task (mobile software)?

Tags: iphone, design, apple, choices

I'm developing a mobile application like the stock Reminders.app offered by Apple, and I'm deploying a "snooze" functionality for overdue tasks.

I'm not sure what the optimal snooze time is or how to figure it out. Is there research or standards on snooze times for tasks on mobile apps? What would be the correct way to determine the snooze time?

My thinking is 1 hour but I don't have anything to back that up.

Comment: Can you give further details on what the app does? It is difficult to guess a time frame which is suitable without knowing the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allow the user to set his own default snooze time and so that can be customized so that he can set when he wants to be reminded.What might seem like an optimal snooze time for you might not be for others.

For example, I like to set my alarm snooze time as 10 minutes though for my reminder apps I set it as one hour as I know that if I cannot attend the reminder now, I wont be able to do it for an hour. However that might not apply for everyone and would depend upon each user and the urgency of the task.

Here is an [apple forum post which complains about the inablity to change the snooze time is very annoying](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4137906?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: Thank you. But then what time intervals should I let the user choose?

Comment: I would say allow them to choose any interval they want,for ideas on how to do it look at the any.do app which handles it well by providing an option to have a defined interval to predefined intervals like one day or one hour